# Save to excel file using openpyxl instead of csv

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, openpyxl

[image]The code below is working and is currently saving to a csv file, however I want to save to an excel file instead using openpyxl.  I attempted it further below but had no success. I'd eventually like to save this to an existing sheet and be able to overwrite the existing data.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

Working Code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import urllib    

def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]


url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

try:

    selector = '.js-field-total.tv-screener-table__field-value--total'
    condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    matches = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
    matches = int(matches.text.split()[0])

except (TimeoutException, Exception):
    print ('Problem finding matches, setting default...')
    matches = 4895 # Set default

# The page loads 150 rows at a time; divide matches by
# 150 to determine the number of times we need to scroll;
# add 5 extra scrolls just to be sure
num_loops = int(matches / 150 + 5)

for _ in range(num_loops):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(1) # Pause briefly to allow loading time

search_entries = [
    ("tickers",       "//tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a"),
    ("rev annual",      "//tbody/tr/td[10]"),
    ("income",          "//tbody/tr/td[11]")]          

with open('textfile.csv', 'w+', newline= '' ) as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Write header
    csv_output.writerow([name for name, xpath in search_entries])
    entries = []

    for name, xpath in search_entries:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))

    csv_output.writerows(zip(*entries))
```

Tried this:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from openpyxl import Workbook
import urllib   

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet() 

def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]


url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

try:

    selector = '.js-field-total.tv-screener-table__field-value--total'
    condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    matches = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
    matches = int(matches.text.split()[0])

except (TimeoutException, Exception):
    print ('Problem finding matches, setting default...')
    matches = 4895 # Set default

# The page loads 150 rows at a time; divide matches by
# 150 to determine the number of times we need to scroll;
# add 5 extra scrolls just to be sure
num_loops = int(matches / 150 + 5)

for _ in range(num_loops):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(1) # Pause briefly to allow loading time

search_entries = [
    ("tickers",       "//tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a"),
    ("rev annual",      "//tbody/tr/td[10]"),
    ("income",          "//tbody/tr/td[11]")]    


entries = []

for name, xpath in search_entries:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))     

wb.save('new_big_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thankyou Azat for you advice.